# ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'import streamlit as st'

Tags: python

I have a `requirements.txt` file containing:

`streamlit`

Running

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I get:

```
ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'import streamlit as st' (from line 1 of requirements.txt)
```

What's the problem?

Comment: your `requirements.txt` file should contain the package names to download and install, not the actual import statements

Comment: I'm not clear - is the problem to do with my requirements.txt or the command line I'm running - i.e. `pip install ... etc`